# How to remove Woocommerce cart notifications?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, elementor

**Question:**
How to remove the Woocommerce cart notifications as:  "Product was removed from cart", "Product was added to your cart", "Show cart".

**Platform:**
Wordpress & Woocommerce

**Theme:**
Astra

**Plugin:**
Elementor Pro

See photos for notifications I want to be removed.

**Added to cart:**

[image: Added to cart]

**Removed from cart:**

[image: Removed from cart]

What I have already done is removing the coupon code from the checkout page through some code in the functions.php but I don't know if it's possible to remove these notifications through code or other options?

Answer (score 0):

Here is hook to remove "Add to cart notifications" use this in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'dont_show_message');
function dont_show_message( $message, $products ) { 
    return ''; 
};
```

Or simply yon can use CSS to hide the same.